# Solving Audio Captcha using Puppeteer and 2Captcha

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, captcha, 2captcha

I'm trying to read the audio captcha but am unable to read it. It's showing me undefined.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  const audioFilePath = 'D:\\amazon_reviews\\audio.mp3';

  const audioBuffer = fs.readFileSync(audioFilePath);
  const base64Data = audioBuffer.toString('base64');

  request.post({
    url: 'http://2captcha.com/in.php',
    formData: {
      key: 'my_key',
      body: base64Data,
    }
  }, async (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(body)
      const captchaId = body.split('|')[1];
      request.get({
        url: `http://2captcha.com/res.php?key=my_key&action=get&id=${captchaId}`
      }, async (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } else {
          const captchaText = body.split('|')[1];
```

I don't to how to deal with this. I am try to integrate puppeteer and 2captcha but getting undefined. It is unable to read the audio.mp3 file.

Comment: Please, review the data that you sent to the API: https://2captcha.com/api-docs/audio. I suggest you to use postman to try first!